# How to display blog category by same author in wordrpess

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to display blog post category list by same author in author page in wordpress, below the code I have written, but I display me all the list of category rather that displaying author written post category.

```
<ul>
<?php 
wp_list_categories( array(
'orderby'    => 'name',
'show_count' => true,
) ); 
?> 
</ul>
```

Comment: you should use custom query to fetch all posts that author wrote and then get all categories from that.

Comment: hi @AliQorbani I did that and all post related to author working fine, but not able to fetch author post caterogy

Comment: use `foreach` loop all the post, and then get the category_ids of each post. after that merge all the category_ids, at the end use wp_list_categoies() function and pass the Ids to that